# Overriding instance variable array’s operators in Ruby and scoping

Tags: ruby, arrays, singleton

I have a test class and a box class, in the test class i have a var called boxHolder, which is an array, i want to override the << method for this array. Inside the singleton how can i access moski_call ?

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :boxHolder

  def initialize()
   super
   self.boxHolder = Array.new

   class << @boxHolder
     def <<(box)
       box.setPositionWithinColumn(moski_call)
       super(box)
     end
   end
  end   

  def moski_call
    "YAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
  end
end

class Box
  def initialize
  end

  def setPositionWithinColumn(str)
    puts "got a string #{str}"
  end
end

# test
box = Box.new
test = Test.new
test.boxHolder
```

Comment: By convention, rubyists don't use camelCase; it's `box_holder`, not `boxHolder`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
# need this or else `moski_call` method is looked up in context of @boxholder
moski_call_output = moski_call

class << @boxholder; self; end.send(:define_method, :<<) { |box| 
     box.setPositionWithinColumn(moski_call_output)
     super(box)
}
```

Comment: i am getting the following error: "`<<': undefined local variable or method `moski_call' for []:Array (NameError)"

Comment: Ah, this works, many thanks ... can you please explain why this works, defining moski_call_output solved the problem, but whats the difference between moski_call and  moski_call_output ?

Comment: @moski, `moski_call` is a method and `moski_call_output` is a local variable. In a `define_method` block methods are looked up in the object the method is defined on - in this case `@boxholder`. However @boxholder does not have such a method and so it will error. local variables on the other hand are captured by the `define_method` block (closure) and will be accessible.

Comment: `moski_call_output` won't get updated if `moski_call` changes... I posted a solution I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def self.boxHolder.<< (box)
   box.setPositionWithinColumn(moski_call)
   super(box)
end
```

This would declare a method for your instance boxHolder. But boxHolder does not have access to the method moski_call

Comment: it seems the syntax is not correct, i am getting "syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '\n' or ';'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain access to the "parent" `Test` object. This can be done using the fact that blocks are closures:

```
parent = self # to be accessible in the closure

@boxHolder.define_singleton_method(:<<) do |box|
  box.setPositionWithinColumn(parent.moski_call)
  super(box)
end
```

*Note*: `define_singleton_method` is new in Ruby 1.9, so either upgrade, `require 'backports/1.9.1/kernel/define_singleton_method'` or do `class << @boxHolder; define_method(:<<){ "..." } end` if using an older Ruby.